# Неправильно отображается изображение в ImageView

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот загружаю из каталога изображение размером 1440х2560 в ImageView, на телефоне Samsung Galaxy j1 с разрешением 480 х 800. Почему изображение загружается горизонтально внутри ImageView(автоматически повернуто на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки)? На смартфоне Homtom с разрешением 720 х 1280 все отображается как надо, то есть вертикально. Как это исправить?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>


String path_1 =  "file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "MyFiles/Icons" + "/" + "1.jpg";
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_1);
    img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path_1));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так может просто файл именно так и выглядит?

Comment: информация о ориентации фотографии скорее всего имеется в [exif](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF), вы без особого труда должны найти информацию как эти данные доставать, а уже на основании их поворачивать изображение.

Comment: Спицко Дмитрий, в галереи файл нормально открывается. Ниже правильно написали, ориентация в exif хранится, но толковых примеров я не нашел что-то..